# SSAS adding exisiting cube from one environment to another

Tags: ssas, cubes

I would like to add cubes that are in production environment to Dev Environment. Dev has additional cubes and would like to know if there is a way to add additional cubes from prod without overwriting the cubes in dev environment.

Comment: Are your prod and dev cubes pointed to the same data sources?  If not, do you need the prod cube to still point to prod data when you pull them back into dev?  Also, are you asking how to get the  production cube off of the production SSAS server as well as how to change the name of the cube?

Comment: prod cube will point to dbs on prod server and dev cubes to dbs on dev server. I am looking to export the cube from prod server, add it to dev and update the data sources to dev db. I am not looking to change the name of cube.

Answer (score 3):

You have several options...

1. Take a backup of the production SSAS database and restore it.
2. Generate and XMLA script from the production cubes and run it on dev.
3. Use the Synchronize data wizard in Management Studio (the caveat here is that the account running the SSAS service on the dev environment must have access to the SSAS database in the prod environment).
4. Import the cubes into a BIDS/SSDT project and deploy them to dev.
5. Analysis Services Deployment wizard

[Here is a link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174869.aspx) to TechNet that explains all of your options.

Here is a bit of explanation for the first and fourth option.

1) Take (or ask your dba to take) a backup of the prod cubes and restore them to your dev environment. Information on how to do this can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174874.aspx).  If you do this, you will be restoring an entire SSAS database rather than specific cubes.  So you will end up with 2 SSAS databases on your dev server.

4) Open the production cubes in SSDT by creating a new project and choosing import from server.  Then  change the project settings to deploy that cube to the dev server. 
[image]
Enter the info for the production server and database.

[image]

Once you have the prod SSAS database in your project, change the Project properties so the target server is the dev server and deploy the cubes.

Comment: Thanks Marie. I am going to look into it. But I have a question. Both Prod and Dev environments each have one datasource view.when I compare both datasource views, some of the tables doesnt match. so, if I use XMLA script to deploy new cubes on dev, am I going to end up with two datasource views on dev environment.