# Copy a cube to new server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, cube

I am trying to replicate the cube which exists on the `live server` over to our new `test server`. I read the following [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766323/ssas-adding-exisiting-cube-from-one-environment-to-another) and decided to go with his option number 1 (Backing up the SSAS databases). This is complete and ran successfully on both servers. backup ran without error and restore ran without error.

**Here are the DB's on the new server:**

[image]

What i tried next was accessing this information through Excel & SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) in Visual Studio. Neither could connect to the SSAS i am assuming.

My question is, am I replicating the cube correctly or am i doing it horribly wrong? I have not found much information on how to copy a cube over to another server, or maybe I am lacking good Google skills.

Any help and other articles would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Are you able to browse the cube on the new server in SSMS?

Comment: @TabAlleman I can right click and click browse yes, no error there either.

Comment: Then you copied the database over fine.   Is that really all you needed to know?

Comment: @TabAlleman No, so i can access the cube in SSMS but i cannot access it in Excel or Visual studio. Any ideas as to why that is?

Comment: What happens when you try?   Any error message?